# How do I set up the R Script folder in QGIS 2.8.1 Processing Toolbox (Advanced Interface)?

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-processing, toolbox

I am currently lacking the R Script folder in my processing toolbox under the advanced interface tab. I suspect this could be a result of the firewall in my company's wifi.

I already have R installed, just need to figure out how to link it. Preferably a method that does not require administrative rights.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joseph, Its very easy and helpfull after reading this.
Sharad sharad.env@gmail.com

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/97341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using QGIS 2.8.1 but I think the following procedure should still be similar (I use 2.6.1):

- Select from the toolbar, *Processing* > *Options and configuration* > *Providers* > *R scripts*.
- Set the directory to where you installed R and make sure you enable *Activate*.

[image: Processing options]

- Once done then click *OK* and you should see it in the *Processing Toolbox*. If not then try restarting QGIS.

[image: R in Processing Toolbox]

Hope this helps!